# How to filter single data from array using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var auditorListValue = ["", "1", "2", "3", "4"];
var oldAuditGroupId = 3;
var auditorListValue = auditorListValue.filter(function (item) {
 return item !== oldAuditGroupId;
});
console.log(auditorListValue);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>


</html>
```

I want to remove this **"3"** from array and push remaining data into array but it is not working. I have tried this same method for other array but it is working,but it is not working for this array.

Answer (score 1):

It is because in your original array you have strings and you are comparing strings to a number using `!==`. IT will always return `false` unless both of the items have the same type or you compare using `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var auditorListValue = ["", "1", "2", "3", "4"];
var oldAuditGroupId = "3";
var auditorListValue = auditorListValue.filter(function (item) {
    return item !== oldAuditGroupId;
});
console.log(auditorListValue);
```

This will work!!!
You are filtering integer instead of String.

I hope you understand!!!!